# Why is the lambda maximum resident set size greater than the size on the local system?

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to run a python code using `usr/bin/time` to get the value of Maximum resident set size. On the local system it's showing around 8000 kbytes but when I'm doing the same on lambda it's showing around 22400 kbytes, which is about 3 times larger than on the local system.

The most possible "why" for this I think of is that lambda assigns the memory according to CPU usage. Is this correct? If not, what is the reason for the difference?